# The mouseEvent in a function fires twice if call again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, unbind

The problem is I would like to fire only once when the mouseevent function is triggered, e.g.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu").click(function(){
         $('#menu_div').show();
         menu_function();
     });


     $("#menu_close").click(function(){
         $('#menu_div').hide();
     });
 });

function menu_function(){
    $(".select_li").live(
        "click",
        function() {
            alert("test");
        }
    );
}
```

The example has two objects, menu and menu close; when the menu press, the ui box is shown, and run the menu_function , which fires an alert test message. The problem is when the menu_close is clicked and box closed, and open it again, the alert test will fire twice. I observe that the times of div box close and open again is the same as the fire times of the function, how can I fix it?

If I would like not using unbind, are there any better solution?

Comment: adding the relevant html code, or building a minimal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates your issue would greatly help any of those attempting to help you.

Comment: I normally downvote questions that contain unformatted code, but won't this time - please consider indenting the code in your questions in the future. It makes them _much_ easier to read for people helping you!

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting, the problem is explained by jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your menu_function() is NOT just firing an alert test message - it is adding a live click listener to everything in the DOM that has a class of "select_li" that fires a test alert. This means that every time you click on #menu you are adding ANOTHER listener to .select_li - so if you click #menu 10x, you should have 10 listeners for each click of .select_li.

If you are truly trying to JUST show an alert when you click on #menu, your menu_function() should only look like this:

```
function menu_function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, because I need to use a button to open a div menu, and on the menu I need to press a button to alert test.That means I need to make a class?

Comment: Please clarify what you meant by that question - I am not really sure what you are asking? If it is unrelated to the above question or completely different, you can consider opening a new question. If it is like the above question, please clearly spell out exactly what you are looking to do and provide a jsfiddle representation if it is applicable.